# How to use "Method: projects.repos.create" to mirror bitbucket repo

Tags: bitbucket, google-apis-explorer, google-cloud-build, google-source-repositories

I want to Mirror bitbuket repo in Google Source Repository so, what should I need to pass in below json request body.

````
{
  "mirrorConfig": {
    "url": "",
    "deployKeyId": "",
    "webhookId": ""
  },
  "name": "",
  "pubsubConfigs": {}
}```
````

Comment: where can I find deployKeyId

Comment: I want to mirror all bitbucket repos to google source repositories

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the `projects.repos` [resource reference](https://cloud.google.com/source-repositories/docs/reference/rest/v1/projects.repos), the `mirrorConfig` field is currently set to read-only, so it is not possible to set any values for it manually.

Currently it is not possible to mirror the repository via the API, you will have to connect to the external sources through the Cloud Console, like explained in the [Mirroring a Bitbucket repository](https://cloud.google.com/source-repositories/docs/mirroring-a-bitbucket-repository) documentation.